# Game server gateway design

Tags: java, asynchronous, message-queue, netty

I am trying to build a generic server for always on connected clients.

The architecture consists of 4 main components

- Stateful App Servers
- Stateless Gateway Servers
- Clients
- Queueing Systems and brokers

Process flow

1. Client connects to a gateway
2. Gateway accepts as sends a session id back to client
3. Client sends a message to gateway
4. The Gateway writes the request to a Message / Task Queue
5. A daemon reads the messages on the Queue and forwards them to the App Server(s)'s listening socket
6. The App Servers runs the message through its business logic
7. The App Server then at a later point sends a related message to the client into the gateway queue
8. A thread on the gateway reads the messages in its inbound queue and then sends messages back to clients as identified in the message.
9. The gateway maintains a map of Client Session Id to the Client Socket object to forward incoming messages to the Client Sockets

I am using Java Netty for gateway. App server is also in Java.

I am tempted to say that the design is like Mongrel2 but I am not completely sure. I would say this is more on the lines of the Helium edge server design of Urban Airship (http://urbanairship.com/blog/2010/08/24/c500k-in-action-at-urban-airship/)

My question is:
- Is using a thread for reading messages from the inbound queue and then forwarding them to clients a good idea? Is there a better way to handle this?

Comment: the term 'workers' comes to mind

Comment: How can the term workers help me in sending the messages back to clients after reading from a inbound queue?

Answer (score -1):

You might be aware that this type of application already exists in terms of cloud services, so you don't have to reinvent the wheel. Search the hp.com website.

Comment: What exactly am I to search for in the hp.com website?